# Does Google Analytics Browser Size Analysis work with a Responsive Layout like Bootstrap?

Tags: google-analytics, twitter-bootstrap

Wondering if anyone knows how well **Google's [browser size analysis](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/06/new-feature-conduct-browser-size.html)** works with a responsive design layout such as **Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)**?

Browser Size
[image]

Conversion insight
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very well. I tried to adjust the Google Analytics window to make it force the tablet/mobile flows on bootstrap, but what happens is that the iframe that your site is loaded into has a somewhat fixed width.

If you edit the page html (through Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug) and re-dimension the div element with `id="ID-inPageTab-inpageiframe"` you can bring the width down and see the page with a mobile design. This works very well.

It's a little hackish but it works. Google might possibly add that option in the future,